# creating charts with database data? flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, flutter-hive

Hey Guys I am new to flutter and at the moment I try to create a chart with my database data.
I tried like this:

```
class DataChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Data> data;

  DataChart({required this.data});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final hiveBox = Hive.box<Data>('dataBox');
    List<charts.Series<Data, String>> series = [
      charts.Series(
          id: "Statistic",
          data: data,
          domainFn: (Data data, _) => data.Fehlstellung.toString(),
          measureFn: (Data data, _) => data.Wiederholung,
      )];
  }
}
```

and that is my data.dart file:

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Data {
  @HiveField(0)
  double Wiederholung;
  @HiveField(1)
  double Satz;
  @HiveField(2)
  double Fehlstellung;

  Data(
      this.Fehlstellung,
      this.Satz,
      this.Wiederholung,
      );

}
```

and that´s my data repository:

```
class Datarepository {
  Future init() async {
    Hive.registerAdapter(DataAdapter());
    var box = await Hive.openBox<Data>('dataBox');
  }

  safeData(Data data) {
    var box =Hive.box<Data>('dataBox');
    box.add(data);

  }
  List<Data> getData(){
    var box =Hive.box<Data>('dataBox');
    return box.values as List<Data>;
  }
}
```

with my current knowledge I don`t know how to solve my problem and I would be very thankful if anyone could help me

Answer (score 0):

In my flutter projects I use the following flutter package for charts:
https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart

Another good flutter package for charts is:
https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter

To achieve your goal you can look at the samples and documentation.